# How to input data to inputbox on website and "click" on button

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to access simple WordPress webpage that is locked with password. After logging to that page, I would like to read data. I already test my code for reading the data and it's working, but I don't know how to input text to input box and press button.

```
//*[@id="pwbox-1902"] -> XPATH to input box
//*[@id="content"]/div/form/p[2]/input -> XPATH to submit button
```

Please, how can I do it?
Thanks for any help.

I expect to login to that page and then use my code that worked to read data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours I managed to get it working. My solution isn't the prettiest or the best one, but I am learning with C#.

Down below I post my code, thanks to I managed to login into WordPress page and read data from table. I used Selenium and HTML Agility pack.

I hope that it finds someone useful :)

**Nugget Packages I used:**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

If you have some questions, ask me or if you want to make my code better, I would be happy to see your code.

Have a wonderful day.

**My code:**

```
        public void Login()
    {
        //var driverServices = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        //driverServices.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
        
        using (var browser = new ChromeDriver("Chrome driver path", chromeOptions))
        {
            browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("your website");
            
            browser.FindElement(By.Id("input box where you want add password")).SendKeys("Your password");
            browser.FindElement(By.Name("Submit")).Click();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Hosts", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Table", typeof(string));
            int count = 0;

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(browser.PageSource);

            foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"post-580\"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr"))
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
                {
                    count++;

                    switch (count)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            dr["Time"] = cell.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dr["Hosts"] = cell.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            dr["Names"] = cell.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            dr["Email"] = cell.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            dr["Phone"] = cell.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            dr["Status"] = cell.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            if (cell.InnerText == "  My text   ")
                            {
                                dr["Message"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("  My text   ", "");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dr["Message"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("My text", "");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            dr["Table"] = cell.InnerText;
                            if (cell.InnerText == "")
                            {
                                dr["Table"] = "My text";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dr["Table"] = "My text";
                            }
                            count = 0;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dt_table.DataSource = dt;
            }

            browser.Quit();
        }
```